# Intersection between two (perpendicular) lines

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, geometry-surface

Let's assume I have a (infinite) line defined as `y = z * x` how can I find the closest point in this line to any given coordinate? Technically I seek the intersection between the initial line and its perpendicular passing on the given coordinate.

Comment: I found libraries which check for possible intersections between segments, but I would like to find a simpler formula since I know the intersection exists.

Comment: `y =z * x` is not a line, but a ruled surface. Setting a plane (e.g. z= k) gives a line and the problem becomes a 2D case, very documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `(x, zx)` be a point on the given line, and `(u, v)` the outside point.

The squared distance is

```
(x - u)² + (zx - v)² = (z² + 1) x² - 2 (u + zv) x + u² + v²
```

and the minimum of this quadratic expression is achieved by

```
x = (u + zv) / (z² + 1)
```

giving you the orthogonal projection of the point onto the line.

Comment: Something doesn't work on my implementation: https://codepen.io/nuthinking/pen/8b9d12eca5c66011b5645d595c49ae82?editors=0011

Comment: @Nuthinking When I changed your code into y(x) dependence instead of weird mix, it became to work as needed

Comment: @MBo do you have a fork?

Answer (score 0):

I did a line intersection sample a few weeks a go. You could try that:

https://github.com/feldhaus/math-geometry-playground/blob/master/line-intersection/index.html

Comment: looks like a 2 segments intersection.